# How to optimize a delete query with a subselect?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

This query needs to delete over 17 million rows, from a table containing 20 million.

```
DELETE FROM statements 
where agreement_id IN (
    select id FROM agreements 
    WHERE created < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6  MONTH)
);

DELETE FROM agreements 
WHERE created < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6  MONTH)
```

It takes hours to run, am I missing something that could speed things up a bit?

The subselect by itself takes a few seconds, I don't understand why the delete takes so long.

Comment: Please take a look at [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks sufficient detail required to facilitate a comprehensive answer.  Please see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example for more details.  Add the required details, and we'll likely re-open the question.

Comment: You'll probably need a larger `innodb_log_file_size` - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-redo-log.html. A large innodb_buffer_size is also recommended.

Comment: If you are doing these frequently or need to consider resource usage, consider partitioning by the date and dropping a partition.

Comment: You better move 3 million rows into a new table and delete the old one.

Comment: [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) are multiple techniques to deal with big deletes.  Deleting more than a thousand rows at a time is costly because of the undo log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Multiple-Table Syntax* of [DELETE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html).

```
DELETE s.*, a.*
FROM statements s, agreements a
WHERE s.agreement_id = a.id
  AND a.created < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

Comment: I am not sure if it helps with the issue I had, but totally happy with the awesome tip you threw in. 

Karma is the least I could do. Thanks bud.